# AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'alter'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm working on a project that has both older *sqlalchemy-migrate*-based migrations and newer *alembic*-based migrations. I'm trying to remove the former. Ripping it out was easy enough but I'm seeing the following failure when I run some tests after doing so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/user/myproject/.tox/functional/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 747, in __getattr__                                                        
return getattr(self.comparator, key)                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'alter'
```

However, I note that when I re-add an import for the `migrate` (*sqlalchemy-migrate*) module into any of the remaining `alembic` migrations, things start working again? Why does the `alter` method disappar without this module?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was that one of the newer *alembic* migrations was using the `alter` method that *sqlalchemy-migrate* seems to monkey-patch in. Specifically, I needed to change the following:

```py
images = Table('images', meta, autoload=True)
images.c.is_public.alter(nullable=True, server_default=None)
```

to:

```py
with op.batch_alter_table('images') as batch_op:
    batch_op.alter_column('is_public', nullable=True, server_default=None)
```

(I had to do this instead of `op.alter_column` since [that isn't compatible with SQLite](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/batch.html#dropping-unnamed-or-named-foreign-key-constraints)).